Panoramic camera calibration without chessboard method
I have an image of a panoramic video camera (dual lens) in which there is a visible distortion. As the camera it's in a fixed position, and without any zoom or any other movement, and I have a lot of real world points from the soccer pitch witch is recording(and known distances, for example from google maps), as far as I understood... from the cameraCalibrate method... it could be possible to achieve the camera distortion parameters?
calibrateCamera() from Camera Calibration and 3D Reconstruction


what I did in python:
    image = cv2.imread("./data/video.jpg")
    h, w = image.shape[:2]
    image_2d = [[20, 14, 0], [20, 768, 0], [1190, 18, 0], [1190, 773, 0], [604, 14, 0], [603, 390, 0], [603, 769, 0], [141, 390, 0], [1067, 395, 0]] #[LEFT_CORNER_TOP, LEFT_CORNER_BOTTOM, RIGHT_CORNER_TOP, RIGHT_CORNER_BOTTOM, CENTER_TOP, CENTER_CENTER,
                CENTER_BOTTOM, LEFT_PENALTY, RIGHT_PENALTY]

    video_pos = [[1450, 490], [305, 687], [3270, 599], [4396, 894], [2358, 524], [2346, 602], [2272, 1116], [1226, 558], [3482, 690]] #[VIDEO_LEFT_CORNER_TOP, VIDEO_LEFT_CORNER_BOTTOM, VIDEO_RIGHT_CORNER_TOP, VIDEO_RIGHT_CORNER_BOTTOM,
                 VIDEO_CENTER_TOP, VIDEO_CENTER_CENTER, VIDEO_CENTER_BOTTOM, VIDEO_LEFT_PENALTY, VIDEO_RIGHT_PENALTY]
    ret, mtx, dist, rvect, tvect = cv2.calibrateCamera(
        np.array([image_2d], dtype=np.float32),
        np.array([video_pos], dtype=np.float32),
        (w, h), None, None)
    camera_calibration_dict = {
        'ret': ret,
        'mtx': mtx,
        'dist': dist,
        'rvecs': rvect,
        'tvecs': tvect
    }
new_cameramtx, roi = cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx, dist, (w, h), 1, (w, h))
    dst = cv2.undistort(img, mtx, dist, None, new_cameramtx)
    cv2.imwrite('undistort.jpg', dst)

It looks a bit better but still a visible distortion:

UPDATE (Adding all known pitch points):
The center looks a bit better but both sides are worst.





For distortion correction you will need much more points, like a chessboard in various poses.

that's already a composite of two individual cameras. the composite might be warped in ways that are inconsistent with an actual camera model. if you're lucky, it's a cylindrical or equirect or other model... but that is not a "normal" camera model, so the methods you're trying to use don't apply. -- you can't make up for lack of proper camera calibration. a single image just doesn't do the job.

This is exactly why you make photos of the chessboard. By doing photos of the chessboard when board picture is photoed in the corners/edges of the camera picture you are more closely estimate distortion on the edges of the picture. Because you don't have enough markers on the edges of the picture you won't be able to correct the distortion on the edges.

@ChristophRackwitz How would you go about calibrating this camera then? Since this is not a common camera model, I'd imagine a chessboard calibration pattern would not work. What do you mean a single image just doesn't do the job? Is it possible to calibrate with multiple images/viewpoints?

need details on this "panoramic video camera (dual lens)". a non-plot source image would also be helpful.

Hi @ChristophRackwitz, thank you for your comments. Really appreciate. I've added a new image without the axis. The camera is a 4mm, 1/2.8'' sensor with 170º angle view. Let me know if you need anything else. The image resolution it's 4608x1260 and the real pitch size it's 105x68 meters

Found also this post that looks a similar aproach? https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-read-a-label-on-a-wine-bottle-using-computer-vision-part-3-e4729e5a8140

you are allowed to just state the make and model of that panorama device. that would directly provide all of us a lot of info. -- so far, you said "dual lens". does this mean the lenses taken together cover 360 degrees, and each covers ~180 degrees? in that case, MAYBE, your picture comes from a single camera/lens. maybe not. that has not been stated definitely. -- sure you can calibrate the individual lenses/cameras in your device. even if the lenses are fisheye lenses. -- I have no experience calibrating fisheye lenses, and not enough practice calibrating non-fisheyes.

It covers 85º for each len, so the final angle covered it's 170º having as result the image used.  The model is only availabre for buy in China (https://www.tp-link.com.cn/product_2138.html)

I browsed the site and used google to translate some of the pictures of text. I did not find details on the projection they generate. did you see mention of "cylindrical", "mercator", or "equirectangular" map projections? I'm not set up to quickly try those hypotheses but those would be worth a try. if the resulting view looks plausible... figuring this out is a prerequisite for pose estimation.

ok, thank you @ChristophRackwitz I didn't see that technical details anywhere but I will try to ask the seller.

assuming 169 degrees HFoV, it does kinda look straight in a generic online panorama viewer. 162 degrees looks better, also happens to figure to 10240x5120 for a full 360x180 panorama. I'd say it's probably equirectangular, with somewhat less than 169 degrees HFoV. with that info, you can generate a top-down view. it's a bit of work to set up the math.

@ChristophRackwitz Sorry, I didn't see the last comment. Do you mean use the remap function as cv2.INTER_LINEAR? Sorry I'm not expert, I'm trying to understand the logic yet, specially the math set up. Thank you again!

@DLara Were you able to solve this issue?
